# SQL - Need help filtering results based on rows

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
p_id | comp_id
-----+--------
 100 | 1
 100 | 2
 101 | 1   
 102 | 1
```

Basically, the `p_id` can be entered multiple times into the table for as many `comp_id` as needed.

What I need is to select all the `p_id`s that have been on `comp_id` 1 and 2. In the above table, that would mean only `p_id == 100` would be returned.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: I wish it were... It's for work.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p_id
FROM Mytable
WHERE comp_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY p_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct comp_id) = 2
```

Ensure your `IN` contains the same number of values as the int in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT t1.p_id
FROM table AS t1
INNER JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.p_id = t2.p_id
WHERE t1.comp_id=1
AND t2.comp_id=2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p_id
  FROM table 
 WHERE comp_id in (1,2)
 GROUP BY p_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT comp_id) = 2
```

or

assumig #t is the following table (the comp_id's you're searching for):

```
comp_id
-------
      1
      2

SELECT t1.p_id
  FROM table t1
 WHERE NOT EXITS (SELECT NULL
                    FROM table t2
              RIGHT JOIN #t
                      ON t2.p_id    = t1.p_id
                     AND t2.comp_id = #t.comp_id
                   WHERE t2.comp_id IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p_id
FROM TABLE 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT P_ID from TABLE where comp_id=1) and EXISTS (SELECT P_ID from TABLE where comp_id=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct p_id from table a 
    inner join table b on a.p_id = b.p_id where a.p_id = 1 and b.p_id = 2
```

this way would probably work but it seems pretty inefficient

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT p_id FROM tbl WHERE EXISTS
 (SELECT p_id FROM tbl WHERE comp_id = 1)
 AND EXISTS (SELECT p_id FROM tbl WHERE comp_id = 2)
```